# is it possible to display complex cgridview at given screenshot in yii framework?

Tags: php, events, yii

Is it possible to achive in CGridview as shown below screenshot.
ON click of "Get More Event" Load 10 more events.
[image: Event Listing]

Otherwise i have to do customize.

Comment: You should do this with CListView.

Comment: Ok. Will try and let you know.

Comment: is there any example or reference link?

Comment: I have tried the same. and it's works thanks davis. But how to append data after current list. Means on click get more events load 10 event after current events instead of pagggin.

Answer (score 0):

Some action:

```
class BlaBlaController extends Controller {

    public function actionView($alias) {
        ...
        $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('ModelClassName');
        $this->render('test', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider
        ));
    }

}
```

protected/blabla/test.php:

```
..
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_itemView', // представление для одной записи
)); ?>
..
```

protected/blabla/_itemView.php:

```
<?php var_dump($data)?>
<hr>
```

Comment: I have tried the same. and it's works as davis said to me on above comment. But how to append data after current list. Means on click get more events load 10 event after current events instead of pagging.

Comment: look at framework/zii/widgets/assets/listview/jquery.yiilistview.js and framework/zii/widgets/listview/CListView.php

Comment: Have seen but don't understand what to do?

Comment: Make your own ListView child of CListView. Insert instead pagination your button for laod next page. Instead jquery.yiilistview.js implement own realisation JS based on jquery.yiilistview.js and use append unstead of replaceWith

Comment: Yes i have tried for append in jquery.yiilistview.js.But it don't affect the changes. Will try and let you know the status. I am looking for inbuilt functionality. So Currently i am not trying to do from scratch.